# Convert .dex file to .jar file using dex2jar

Tags: java, android, jar, dex, dex2jar

I have made an application that converts `.dex file to .jar` file using the library dex2jar.
the code is given as follows:

```
import com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Main;
{
    String apkPath = "D://myapk.apk" ;
    Main.main(apkPath);
}
```

this code block works properly and I am getting asd_dex2jar.jar file, but the problem is after executing calling the main(), the program closes automatically,

so is there any way to do this any another way ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation or the source code: https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/source/browse/dex-translator/src/main/java/com/googlecode/dex2jar/v3/Main.java

Maybe you could just call its `public static void doFile(File srcDex)` method.